# cmyk to ral needed help asap for paint choose

Tags: color

I need to switch those colors for paint code - ral

BLUE（C:80  M:70 Y:50 K:20）

GREEN（C:50  M:0 Y:100 K:0）

can anybody help ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **There can't be an exact match** because RAL is a spot color definition library. You can always try to find a RAL color close to your given CMYK values.

1. Convert your [CMYK values to RGB](http://www.ginifab.com/feeds/pms/cmyk_to_rgb.php) and copy the hex value
2. Look up the closest match using the [rgb.to site](http://rgb.to/hex/)

C80 M70 Y50 K20 translates to RGB #293d66 and closest match is [RAL 5013](http://rgb.to/ral/5013)

C50 M0 Y100 K0 translates to RGB #80ff00 and closest match is [RAL 6038](http://rgb.to/ral/6038)